# How to remove element from postgres jsonb by key value?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have a jsonb column with this format.

```
{
    "categoryList": [{
        "category_menu_id": "51",
        "is_featured_product": 0
    }, {
        "category_menu_id": "54",
        "is_featured_product": 1
    }]
}
```

How to remove category by category_menu_id?

This select query is working fine by category_menu_id.

```
select product_category 
from product  
where product_category->'categoryList' @> '[{"category_menu_id": "51"}]';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example data (note that I have added a primary key `id` to enable updating the table):

```
create table product(id int primary key, product_category jsonb);
insert into product values
(1, 
'{
    "categoryList": [{
        "category_menu_id": "51",
        "is_featured_product": 0
    }, {
        "category_menu_id": "54",
        "is_featured_product": 1
    }]
}');
```

This query skips the element with `"category_menu_id": "51"` from the json array:

```
select jsonb_build_object('categoryList', jsonb_agg(value))
from product,
jsonb_array_elements(product_category->'categoryList')
where value->>'category_menu_id' <> '51';

                            jsonb_build_object                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"categoryList": [{"category_menu_id": "54", "is_featured_product": 1}]}
(1 row)
```

Use the above query to update the table:

```
update product p
set product_category = (
    select jsonb_build_object('categoryList', jsonb_agg(value))
    from product ps,
    jsonb_array_elements(product_category->'categoryList')
    where ps.id = p.id      -- important! primary key to identify a row
    and value->>'category_menu_id' <> '51')
returning *;

 id |                             product_category                             
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"categoryList": [{"category_menu_id": "54", "is_featured_product": 1}]}
(1 row)
```